# SlideUp when click on the content

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile, slidetoggle, slidedown, slideup

I have this code:

```
$("a.shownav").on("click", function(){
    $("div.nav").slideToggle();
});
```

And when I click on the other parts of the page, except for the `div.nav` part, I want the `div.nav` part to slideup. I have tried this but it doesn't seem to work:

```
if ($("div.nav").is(":visible")){
    $("*").not("div.nav").on("click", function(){
        $("div.nav").slideUp();
    });
}
```

How do I achieve what I want?

Comment: have a look at something like Ben Almans clickoutside events plugin http://benalman.com/code/projects/jquery-outside-events/examples/clickoutside/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could handle the click event of the document, get the target object, then test if it is the nav div or a child of the nav div.  If it is not one of the 2, you can close it.

```
$(document).on("click", function(e){
    var targ = $(e.target);
     if (!targ.hasClass("nav") && targ.parents(".nav").length < 1) {
        $("div.nav").slideUp();
    }
});
```

> **[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/ezanker/swz2D/)**